# create pdf from html for old android device

Tags: android, pdf, itext

when i use `itextg:5.5.10` , i cant put html codes into my pdf file, and not exsist `xmlWorker` in library, my target code is

```
 public void createPdf() throws IOException, DocumentException {
    String str = "my html code";
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "logo.pdf");
    OutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    Document document = new Document();
    // step 2
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, fileOutputStream);
    // step 3
    document.open();
    // step 4
    // CSS
    CSSResolver cssResolver =
            XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().getDefaultCssResolver(true);
    // HTML
    HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(null);
    htmlContext.setTagFactory(Tags.getHtmlTagProcessorFactory());
    htmlContext.setImageProvider(new Base64ImageProvider());
    // Pipelines
    PdfWriterPipeline pdf = new PdfWriterPipeline(document, writer);
    HtmlPipeline html = new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, pdf);
    CssResolverPipeline css = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, html);
    // XML Worker
    XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(css, true);
    XMLParser p = new XMLParser(worker);
    p.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes()));
    // step 5
    document.close();
}
```

that doesnt resolve `CSSResolver`,`XMLWorkerHelper` and... in library.

Comment: It seems that you are missing the xmlworker jar.

Comment: where i can get it?

Comment: https://github.com/itext/itextpdf/tree/develop/xmlworker